# .bin/authorize-ios not found when installing appium using npm install -g appium

Tags: macos, appium, npm-install, appium-ios

When I try to install appium using `npm install -g appium`

I get the message

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/.bin/authorize-ios
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/.bin/authorize-ios'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

If I run the install again I get

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

The first .bin/authorize-ios is indeed not there. I don't know how to fix it. When I install using `npm install appium-ios-driver` the driver is installed under `User/node_modules` and not at `usr/local/lib/node_modules`. I installed npm using brew.

Comment: We are also getting this. Did you report this on their github tracker? https://github.com/appium/appium/issues

Answer (score 10):

I was able to solve this by installing the NPM 6 (6.14.9 as of this writing)

```
npm i -g npm@6
npm i -g appium
```

If you want to lock into a particular version of npm instead of latest then this should get you to a version that should install it

```
npm i -g npm@6.14.9
```

Comment: `npm i -g npm@latest` worked for me. It changed version on `npm` to `6.14.9` form `7.0.14`

Comment: Note this was a bug in appium that it did not support >= npm7. It has since been fixed but not sure what version will contain the fix: https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/14901

Comment: Unfortunately, the above did not work for me, still getting the same error message.

Comment: Update:  `npm i -g npm@latest` now installs npm 7, so you'll need to explicitly specify you want npm 6: `npm i -ig npm@6`

Answer (score 0):

authorize-ios is deprecated. [appium authorize-ios](https://github.com/appium-boneyard/authorize-ios)

removing appium, updating npm, cleaning the cache and re-installing appium via npm worked for us on this issue(updated 4 build agents this way successfully).

```
npm uninstall -g appium && npm install -g npm && npm clean cache --force && npm install -g appium
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a permission issue, I suggest you try it again from scratch:

- npm uninstall -g appium or just go and delete `/usr/local/bin/appium`
- npm install -g appium@1.18.3

It also makes sense to install appium-doctor to inspect your system has everything setup properly for Appium: `npm install -g appium-doctor`

You can check detailed setup [here](https://medium.com/@ilovemark/appium-installation-and-configuration-under-macos-edd2375dcce)

Answer (score -3):

you can use appium desktop, It is very easy, just install and edit configuration(andorid sdk path and jdk path) and start server.